# Simultaneous equation with 6 equations, 6 unknows and a degre of 5

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations

How do I solve this simultaneous 
$$a + b + c = 2\to (1)$$
$$ax + by + cz = 0\to (2)$$
$$ax^2 + by^2 + cz^2 = \frac{2}{3}\to (3)$$
$$ax^3 + by^3 + cz^3 = 0\to (4)$$
$$ax^4 + by^4 + cz^4 = \frac{2}{5}\to (5)$$
$$ax^5 + by^5 + cz^5 = 0\to (6)$$
This simultaneous has 6 equations, 6 unknown and some variables are raised to the power of 5.
I have been battling with this question for days now...
The best is could come up with

```
Multiplying equation (2) by $x^2$
```

$$ax^3 + byx^2 + czx^2 = 0\to (7)$$

```
Then (7) - (4) becomes
```

$$by(x^2 - y^2) + cz(x^2 - z^2) = 0\to (8)$$
    Multiplying equation (2) by x^4 then subtracting (6) I have:
$$by(x^4 - y^4) + cz(x^4 - z^4) = 0$$

```
 Which then leads to:
```

$$y^2 = z^2$$
$$Conclusively, y = \pm z$$
Aside from this, every other thing I have tried is looking way off.
Is there any better way of doing this? Maybe a matrix or something.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: From what you did, my conclusion is case 1: $y^2=z^2$, case 2: $x^2=y^2, z=0$, case 3: $x^2=z^2, y=0$. In each case, you can plug them back to the originals and try again.